# Avoiding proof by induction

Tags: induction, big-list, philosophy

Proofs that proceed by induction are almost always unsatisfying to me. They do not seem to deepen understanding, I would describe something that is true by induction as being "true by a technicality". Of course, the axiom of induction is required to pin down the Natural numbers and certainly seem to be indispensable in one form or another.

However, I am still interested in the following: Are there any "natural" theorems in mathematics that seem unlikely to fall to any method other than induction for whatever reason? I would not include examples that proceed by breaking down a structure into smaller components that are more easily handled - somehow these proofs satisfy whatever criteria for beauty I have in my mind.

An example of a theorem that does have an inductive proof and a more "superior" proof is Fermat's little theorem. It is perfectly possible to prove it by induction but the proof through group theory seems better - perhaps because it is more easily generalizable. I would like examples where it seems like the "neat" proof is unlikely to exist.

This is probably very philosophical and I do not really have a concrete question but I am sure I am not alone in feeling this way.

Comment: Induction is a defining property of integers (it's basically the axiom that says "and there are no more things that are integers").  So any nontrivial proof involving integers is going to either require induction directly, or it will require a (sometimes obvious) theorem that was proven using induction.

Comment: Nearly every result in Ramsey Theory seems to be entirely reliant on induction.  In particular, when dealing with large collections such as "all colorings of $[n]$ using $k$ colors" where we are unable to look at precisely how the terms are specifically colored.  See my homework on Folkman's Theorem [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51310939/folkman.pdf)

Comment: Personally, I like my proof to be very concise, which often means I tend to bypass induction if possible. From a practical point of view, though, induction lends itself to *constructive* proofs, which are most coveted (at least in number theory).

Comment: You mention Fermat's little theorem proved with group theory; I'm afraid that the tools needed to prove it this way (the order of an element is a divisor of the order of the group) require induction (for being able to know the subgroups of the integers). Induction can very deeply hidden in what we're using.

Comment: Although induction seems very natural and intuitive to me and I have never had any feeling of "true by a technicality" resulting from its use, nonetheless when a proposition can be proved either by induction or by a method that avoids induction, I think I've always felt the latter was better.  But not because it avoids induction; rather, in each case, there has been some particular other advantage to the other method, such as its being simpler. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: BTW, no one seriously writes out most inductive arguments except in little kid classrooms.  We usually just say "and this can be proven with induction" and expect you to be smart enough to fill in the details.  Even for complicated structural induction, no one would ever seriously write out a proof when it is just obvious that the theorem is provable by induction.

Comment: @egreg I don't quite understand your comment. Are you saying that induction is needed to define the equivalence class modulo a prime on the integers?

Comment: @Asvin No, it's needed for showing that the subgroups of the integers are of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$ (or to show existence and uniqueness of division with remainder, which is the same).

Comment: Personally, even though proving something also without induction is nice for me as well, induction provides me with an enjoyable sense of "omnipotence" over the integers.

Comment: @DanielV: I have to strongly disagree with that. I know of several  important papers where the main result is proven by a (very nontrivial) inductive argument.

Comment: Proof by minimum counterexample is a way of restating proofs by induction, I think. (Although, I'm guessing you're thinking of annoying algebra-filled induction proofs, such as that proof of the formula for the first $n$ squares. There are other ways of doing those, but those require creativity to come up with.)

Comment: Some theorems cannot be proven without induction (see an example at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/492836/21820, and an interesting related post at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1812833/21820). Also, if you're uncomfortable with induction it's probably because you have never seen the actual **justification** of induction (see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1812833/21820).

Comment: I think you've just seen baby examples where the standard induction proof is boring. For example, the result 1+2+...+n=n(n-1)/2 is a first baby undergrad exercise in induction. Here n(n-1)/2+(n+1)=n(n+1)/2 seems boring, but the "visual" proof where you take two copies reverse one and pair up, is "pretty". But this is not induction vs no-induction. In fact, the "visual" proof is also an induction. You think you dislike induction, but you don't, you just dislike these examples. Generally, induction is the MOST satisfying, because it is constructive: you can just work up to witness any instance.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Write the axioms of number theory (called "Peano arithmetic," or "PA") as $P^-+\mathrm{Ind}$, where $P^-$ is the ordered semiring axioms (no induction), and $Ind$ is the axiom (scheme) of induction. Then a theorem *requires some induction* if it is not provable by $P^-$ alone - that is, if we can find a **model** of $P^-$ in which the theorem is not true.

- As an aside: the equivalence between non-provability and countermodel-existence is (the contrapositive of) [**Gödel's completeness theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem); see [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099531/how-to-verify-satisfialibility-in-a-model-confusions-with-g%C3%B6dels-completeness) for some discussion of what's going on here.

So that lets us make a precise "Question 1:"

> Question 1: Is there a "natural" theorem about natural numbers which requires some induction, in the sense above?

We can refine this. Let's suppose we want to draw a line between "simple" proofs by induction, and "hard" proofs by induction; we allow the former but are skeptical about the latter.

In this case, in the same way that we broke the axioms of number theory up into parts ($P^-$ and $Ind$), we now need to break $Ind$ up into smaller pieces. The usual way of doing this is via the *arithmetical hierarchy*: every formula in the language of arithmetic can be assigned a "level of complexity," and these levels are indexed by natural numbers. $Ind$ can now be written as $\mathrm{Ind}_1+\mathrm{Ind}_2+ \cdots$, where $Ind_n$ is induction for formulas of complexity $n$. Roughly speaking, a formula has complexity $n$ if it can be written with $n$ alternating blocks of quantifiers: e.g., the formula $$p(a)=\text{“ }\forall x\,\forall y\,\exists z\,\forall w\,(x+y+w<z+a)\text{ ''}$$ has complexity 3, since it has the form "$\forall\forall, \exists, \forall$." (I'm being very vague here, and this is slightly incorrect; but it won't cause any problems.)

So we have question 2:

> Question 2: For each $n$, are there "natural" theorems about natural numbers which require $\mathrm{Ind}_n$?

Note that if a theorem requires $\mathrm{Ind}_n$, then it certainly requires some induction; so question 2 is a strengthening of question 1. By the way, this is of course **not** the only way to break up $\mathrm{Ind}$; there are lots of other ways to measure the complexity of an axiom of induction.

---

The answers to both questions are, spectacularly, **YES**; the general question, "How much induction do we need to prove $\varphi$?" is studied - along with similar questions - by the field *Reverse Mathematics*.

Some examples:

- The statement "There are infinitely many primes" is not provable in $P^-$ alone; that is, it requires **some induction**. How much induction exactly? I don't think this is known, but the (very weak) level of induction called *open induction* is known to also not be enough.
- Ramsey's theorem for pairs - the statement, "Any time I color pairs of natural numbers 'Red' or 'Blue,' I can find an infinite set of natural numbers, any pair from which is colored the same as any other pair" - requires some induction. Again, exactly how much is not known, but it's at least $\mathrm{Ind}_2$ - a small but substantial amount of induction. *EDIT: I'm being somewhat sloppy here. Note that Ramsey's theorem isn't expressible in the language of number theory, so I need to look at a more expressive theory which can talk about such things; the theory used for this purpose is usually $RCA_0$, which corresponds in a particularly nice way to the first level of induction + the ability to talk about sets. See Simpson's book (mentioned below) for details on this.*
- A lot of algebraic statements, like "Every ring which is not a field, has a nontrivial proper ideal", actually require **all** the induction that $PA$ has to offer.

---

REFERENCES

Since there's a lot of stuff here, I don't have time to give a complete explanation - but here are some sources:

For basic logic, including Gödel's completeness theorem and what a "model" is, I'm a fan of Enderton's "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic" - but there are lots of books out there on the same subject, and any of them will do.

For the arithmetical hierarchy, this will be covered in any good logic textbook, but can also be found in a lot of books on theoretical computer science - I'm pretty sure it's in Arora/Barak, for example.

For reverse mathematics, this is trickier; there isn't really any readable introduction. The classic text is Simpson's "Subsystems of Second-Order Arithmetic," and chapter I is very nice and readable, but the rest is very hard.

Comment: I believe that most people around here (myself included) are non familiar with model theory. I assume that by ordered semiring axioms you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations)? It would be nice if you could expand on what you mean by "induction for formulas of complexity $n$" and if you could provide some references for further reading.

Comment: Thanks, this answer exceeded my expectations. I will accept in a little while if no better answers come up.

Comment: Can "open iduction" be somehow compared with any of the $Ind_n$? (Excellent answer, by the way)

Comment: More than the answer, I am impressed at the clear, formal meaning you gave to the question.

Comment: I thought (infinite) Ramsey's theorem could not be proven in PA? For a very readable brief introduction to reverse mathematics, I found https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~htowsner/prooftheory/ReverseMath.pdf

Comment: I just saw this again and realized that you hadn't answered my question... In fact, your recent answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1896346 contradicts what you say here, saying that you can't even state infinite Ramsey's theorem in PA...

Comment: @user21820 There's no contradiction, I just avoided some details. Ramsey's theorem can be stated in the language of second-order arithmetic, which is the usual context for **reverse mathematics**. Over the base theory $RCA_0$ - which actually doesn't even imply all of $PA$, it's a conservative extension of a subtheory of $PA$ - Ramsey's theorem for pairs implies some arithmetic statements (that is, some of the induction in $PA$). So it's completely correct to write that Ramsey's theorem requires some induction, I'm just not going into all the formal details because they're messy. (cont'd)

Comment: I've edited to clarify this, though. Meanwhile, I don't see how this *doesn't* answer your question. I've given several examples of natural theorems which provably require induction, and explained what that meant. What more did you want?

Comment: To your last comment, I'm not the asker! I meant my question in my earlier comment in July, which I had forgotten about until I came across this thread again. It's great that you've edited to clarify your statement here, which indeed is as I expected (using a second-order language, not just that of PA). Don't worry about the formal details; I'm not asking for you to expend any unnecessary energy. =)

Comment: @user21820 Whoops. :P The answer to your question is, you're exactly right! $PA$ can't prove Ramsey's theorem for pairs ($RT^2_2$) because it can't even express it. However, if we look at the *first-order consequences* of $RT^2_2$ - that is, the set of sentences in the language of arithmetic which are provable in the theory $RCA_0+RT^2_2$ - we find that these are all already consequences of $PA$. That is, $PA$ can't "see" $RT^2_2$, but $RT^2_2$ doesn't give you anything $PA$ *can* see that $PA$ can't already prove for itself.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Yes that is certainly one of the facts that I found very interesting when I heard/read about it, since over ACA0 (which is itself conservative over PA) the infinite Ramsey theorem is strong enough to prove the strengthened finite Ramsey theorem, which in turn can be stated in PA but is independent of PA, but yet over RCA0+PA the infinite Ramsey theorem does not add new first-order consequences. But I know too little in this area so I better not comment too much. (See I've had to edit my comment so many times because I got it wrong...) =)

Answer (score 5):

How about the following: Given collections $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ of real numbers, then for all $n$: $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i + \sum_{i=1}^nb_i=\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)$.

If that is what you are looking for then I'm sure you can come up with millions of other such examples.

Comment: I don't think this is an example of what the OP wants, although it is admittedly difficult to precisely enunciate why.  The above statement is "natural" but not a "natural theorem": it is a manifestly true consequence of the definitions that (like almost any statement that quantifies over the natural numbers) requires induction to *formally prove*.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I think this is a natural theorem. I think what the OP means with 'natural theorem' is a result that occurs in standard mathematical practice (as opposed to some weird statement constructed for a specific purpose and which will not be used for anything else). I still agree that this doesn't answer the question because 1) I don't know how to prove it if not by induction, 2) the definition of $\Sigma$ itself requires the recursion theorem.

Comment: @Git Gud: The term "natural theorem" is certainly up for grabs, but to me such a thing should imply that I could imagine one experienced student of mathematics asking another "What's the proof?"  And: if you treat foundational issues lightly/informally (as is typical in most mathematical practice), there is still something to say.  This example does not meet either criterion.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I would argue on a semantic level  that 'a manifestly true consequence of the definitions' is exactly what a theorem is. In this relation, most of what is taught in an introductory linear algebra course would also fall in this category. Surely it is natural material, and I doubt you would get far without arguments based on induction.

Comment: @GitGud OP was looking for something that can't be proven other than by induction, so I don't quite understand objection 1. As for objection 2, OP did not specify not to use recursion in defining the problem. It is perhaps a meta-theorem that any result that ultimately depends on induction to establish must rely on a concept defined recursively.

Comment: @IttayWeiss The reasons I gave are exactly the reasons why I think yours is a good answer. I had completely forgot about what the OP was looking for.

Comment: gotcha @GitGud :)

Answer (score 4):

The [Baire Category Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) is equivalent to the [Axiom of Dependent Choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choices), and therefore you would not expect to be able to find what you call a neat proof. It may if course not be exactly what you are looking for, precisely because induction alone is not enough to prove the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exact answer to your question (I'm nowhere that smart), but if you need to derive something like a closed-form expression, but don't like using an inductive proof, you can try a thing called perturbation method introduced by Graham et al in $Concrete \ Mathematics$ (1995). Here's the simplest example: show the closed-form for $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k$. The first step, denote $V_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$:
$$
V_{n+1} = V_n + a_{n+1} = V_n + (n+1)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 + (n+1)^2  = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(k+1)^2 + 1 = V_n+2S_n + n+1
$$
$V_n$ cancel out, and after a bit of algebra you get of course $S_n = \binom{n+1}{2}$.