# Is this mathematical induction or not, and does it matter? And what known proofs have this form?

Tags: logic, induction

Suppose one proves that for all $n\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\},$ $a_n=a_1$ by means of showing that for every value of $n$ we have $a_{n+1} = a_n,$ the proof being the same for all values of $n.$

If one puts it that way, it looks like mathematical induction: The induction hypothesis is that $a_n=a_1,$ and one uses that in proving that $a_{n+1}=a_1,$ by using the transitivity of equality.

But now suppose the proposition to be proved is stated as $ a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = \cdots.$ Then when one proves that $a_{n+1}=a_n,$ one is not using the previous case, which says $a_{n-1} = a_n,$ so in that respect it does not look like mathematical induction.

- Is the question of whether this really is or is not mathematical induction substantial, or is this trivial semantic nitpicking?
- What known proofs have this form?

This question was inspired by [this video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-o3eB9sfls), where the following is proved by means of elementary geometry:

Suppose a circle centered at $(0,0)$ has **circumference** $2^n.$ Consider the set of $2^{n-1}$ points
$$
S = \left\{ \text{radius} \times\Big( \cos\left( \tfrac{2\pi k} n\right), \sin \left( \tfrac{2\pi k} n \right) \Big) : \textbf{odd } k  \right\}.
$$
Let $$a_n = \sum_{x\,\in\, S} \|x - (1,0)\|^{-2}.$$ Then $$a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = \cdots\left({} = \frac {\pi^2} 4\right).$$

This yields a solution to the celebrated “Basel problem” since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \sum_{\textbf{odd } k\,\in\,\mathbb Z} \frac 1 {k^2}.
$$

Comment: Should say:  I'm not sure I understand the issue regarding induction.  The two versions of the proposition are different.  The first asserts that $a_i=A$ for all $i$, the other asserts merely that all the $a_i$ are equal.  If you want to establish that the common value is $A$ you will need some base case in addition to the argument showing equality, which will (I think) make the two proofs look identical.  Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @lulu : Alright, let's phrase it like this: There is some number $A$ for which for all $n$ we have $a_n=A. \qquad$

Comment: Sure, so then the result "$a_n=a_{n-1}$ plus the (trivial) base case $a_1=a_1$ shows $a_n=a_1$ for all $n$, by standard induction.

Comment: $a_1=a_2=a_3=...$ or $a_1=a_2=a_3=...=\frac{\pi}{4}$ are probably not formulas in the language. So, let's assume that you want to prove that $\forall m\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, a_n=a_m$. One can get this universally quantified formula from the universally quantified formula $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, a_n=A$ without using induction, ignoring whether induction can potentially be needed to define the particular $A$ and/or the $S$ in your concrete example. One only needs to use the transitivity of $=$ and inference rules like universal generalization and instantiation.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy : But the method of proof is still the proof that $a_n = a_{n+1}$ for every $n. \qquad$

Comment: It seems to me that for the second version the induction is implicit in the conclusion since $a_{n}=a_{n+1}$ for each $n$ all the $a_i$ are equal; if one is strict this needs proof, by induction.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Do you mean proving that the right-hand side $\sum_{x\in S}\|x-(1,0)\|^{-2}$ is independent of $n$?

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy : Which of my utterances is the one about which it is asked whether I mean that? Certainly that is what is proved in the video, by elementary geometry.

Comment: It is never clear what you really mean when you try to speak about mathematics. So, one has to cover all the bases.

Comment: "Then when one proves that an+1=an, one is not using the previous case, which says an−1=an, so in that respect it does not look like mathematical induction. "  But that *IS* exactly what mathematical induction does. If it doesn't look like induction that's because you never looked under the hood.  When you say $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ and wipe your hand and walk away, if instead you asked "but *why* does that mean it's always true" and peeked under the hood you'd see $P(1)\implies P(2);P(2)\implies P(3)... P(n-1)\implies P(n);P(n)\implies P(n+1); ....$.  This is induction. Plain and simple.

Comment: @fleablood : Maybe you need to look more closely at what was said here. When do you find in the second method anything that says $P(n) \Longrightarrow P(n+1) \text{?}$

Comment: $P(n)$ is the statement $a_1 =a_2=a_3=.....=a_n$.  Proving $a_n = a_{n+1}$ is the inductive step.  To claim that this is not induction because you statement is only $P(n)$ is the statement is $a_{n-1}=a_{n}$, s to need actually finish your proof and to never conclude that that $a_i$ are actually equal to each other.

Comment: @fleablood : But that's not really induction unless the statement $P(n)$ is USED in the proof of $P(n+1). \qquad$

Comment: But isn't it?  You can't conclude that if you have  $a_n = a_{n+1}$ that $a_{1}=a_2 =.....=a_n = a_{n+1}$ if $P(n)$ *only* states that $a_{n-1} = a_n$.  If that is your statement and *all* you trying to prove is $a_{n} = a_{n+1}$ you don't need any induction but you haven't proven *anything* about all the $a_i$ only $a_n, a_{n+1}$ pairs.  To conclude that $a_1 = a_2$ and $a_2 = a_3$ and ... so on means that $a_1 = a_2=a_3=....$ don't you need to use *both* $P(n)$ and $P(n+1)$ to conclude $a_{n-1} = a_n = a_{n+1}$?

Comment: @fleablood : Indeed you cannot conclude that if you have $a_n= a_{n+1}$ then $a_1 = \cdots = a_{n+1}$ by basing that conclusion only on what you're calling $P(n).$ But it's NOT based on that. Rather it's based on the fact that you have all of the statements $a_n=a_{n+1}$ for $n\in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}. \qquad$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a precise sense in which induction is needed: there are models of PA$^-$ *(= first-order Peano arithmetic without induction)* which have a definable function $f$ such that

- $f(n)=f(n+1)$ for all $n$, but
- there is some $m$ such that $f(m)\not=f(0)$.

*Basically, let $M$ be **any** model of PA$^-$ in which induction fails for some formula $\varphi(x)$, and let $f$ be defined by $f(x)=0$ if $\forall y<x(\varphi(y))$ and $f(x)=1$ otherwise.*

This shows that the "local" fact that each term is the same as the next isn't enough to conclude the desired "global" fact without some induction principles. Here your "$a_n$" is my "$f(n)$." Note that we're not looking at any specific argument here, but rather making a general observation about what axioms are needed to prove the theorem using *any* method.

---

As someone interested in [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics), I'd say that the question of what exactly constitutes induction is quite interesting. However, when it comes to the question "what known proofs have this form," I'm honestly a bit unclear on what exactly the form of proof you have in mind is; I think the argument given would need to be made more explicit to answer that. In general, I would say that proofs tend harder than theorems when it comes to characterization: we have precise ways to talk about when two theorems/questions are equivalent, but telling when two proofs are similar is in my opinion still something we can't satisfyingly do.

Comment: See also [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1200199/28111).

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, you can prove by a single application of proof by induction that $\forall x\in N: a_x=a_1$.

Then you can use this result to prove, without further use of induction, that $\forall x, y \in N: a_x = a_y$ since $a_x=a_1$ and $a_y=a_1$ implies $a_x=a_y$ by substitution. That's the easy way. You can also do it the hard way with a double application of proof by induction with the base case for the first application itself requiring a full proof by induction.