# Prove: If $a\in\mathbb Z$ and $|a| > 1$, then $1/a \notin \mathbb Z$.

Tags: absolute-value

Prove: If $a$ is an integer and $|a| > 1$, then $1/a$ is not an integer.

Hi, I need help proving this either by contradiction or contrapositive. I'm not sure where to begin

Comment: It's not true. Suppose $a \in \mathbb Z = 3 >1$. $\;\frac 1a = \frac 13 \notin \mathbb Z$

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm not understanding it correctly: $2\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\vert 2 \vert >1$, but $\frac{1}{2} \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The statement is blatantly false if $Z$ is meant to be the integers. Do you perhaps mean it to be something else?

Comment: May be the question is $\dfrac{1}{a} \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @boywholived sorry, you are correct. how would i do that with a formal proof?

Comment: The question's title and its first line contradict each other. Apparently it must be $\;\frac1a\notin\Bbb Z\;$ in the question's title.

Comment: @Miguelgondu im sorry, you are correct!

Comment: @Timbuc yes you are correct

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $\frac{1}{a} = b$ an integer. I multiply both sides of this equation by a, giving $ab = 1.$  This implies $a = b = \pm 1$ since the only integers who multiply out to $1$ are $\pm 1$ (since they are the [units in the ring of integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29)) . But $|a|>1$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: im sorry, for some reason i can't seem to understand this. are you trying to say that 1/a is an integer?

Comment: Yes, this a proof by contradiction. I suppose that 1/a is an integer b and, using this, I reach the contradiction that |a| = 1. But, this *can't* be the case since you stipulated |a| >1, strictly. Hence, the assumption that 1/a is an integer is false.

Comment: okay, and then how did you get this part? ab=1⟹a=b=±1 (why is a=b)

Comment: could we also prove it using this logic? Assume a ∈ ℤ, then a > 1 or a < -1. But if a =3, then 1/3 ∉ ℤ. By definition of integer, this is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly. I'm not very familiar with formal logic, but I think this proof is sufficient and fairly "logical".

Comment: @Sam what you just wrote is an example of how this is not true, not a full on proof. For example I can come up with an example of integers $a,b$ where $a\neq b$ but $ab = 0$, i.e. $a = 5, b = 0$ but this doesn't prove that for every pair of integers $ab = 0$.

Comment: @Sam Technically the proof he gave is a proof with logic:

Assume $1/a=b \in \mathbb{Z} \implies ab = 1 \implies a = b = 1 \lor a = b = -1 \implies \lvert a \rvert = 1 \Rightarrow \Leftarrow$

Comment: I would say that if you can't assume that there are no positive integers between $0$ and $1$ then you can't assume that the only units in $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm 1$. Certainly I would prove the fact that $ab = 1 \implies a=b=\pm 1$ using the fact that $|a||b|=1$ and $|a|,|b|>1$... Can you prove it otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

If $|a|>1$ then 
$$\quad0<\frac{1}{|a|}\text{ and } \frac{1}{|a|}<1.$$
So, $\frac{1}{|a|}$ is a number between $0$ and $1$. Since there is no integer between $0$ and $1$, we conclude that $\frac{1}{|a|}\notin\mathbb Z$.

**EDIT:** *Proof by contradiction, as you want:*

Suppose $\frac{1}{|a|}$ is an integer. Since $|a|>1$, we conclude that 
$$\quad0<\frac{1}{|a|}\text{ and } \frac{1}{|a|}<1.$$
So, $\frac{1}{|a|}$ is an integer between $0$ and $1$. But it's a contradiction, because there is no integer between $0$ and $1$. It follows that $\frac{1}{|a|}\notin\mathbb Z$ and thus $\frac{1}{a}\notin\mathbb Z$ (because $\frac{1}{a}$ is an integer if and only if $\frac{1}{|a|}$ is an integer)

**EDIT 2:** *(to make my answer valid as pointed out by @TomOldfield)*

**There is no integer between 0 and 1.**
*Proof:* Suppose that there exists a number $p\in\mathbb Z\cap (0,1)$. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence defined by $x_n=p^n$. Notice that $x_n\in\mathbb Z\cap (0,1)$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Since $(x_n)$ is strictly decreasing, it follows that $\mathbb Z\cap (0,1)$ does not have a least element. But it contradicts the well-ordering principle. So, $\mathbb Z\cap (0,1)=\varnothing$.

Comment: Saying that there are no integers between $0$ and $1$ is essentially just a restatement of the question. Unless you prove that there are no integers between $0$ and $1$, I don't think this is a valid answer.

Comment: @TomOldfield For that fact (that is just a restatement of the problem), there are a lot of of references on the internet (for example, on [this forum](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476184/prove-that-no-positive-integer-is-both-even-and-odd-and-that-all-positive-integ/476262#476262)). However, to make a valid answer for people who think like you, I've edited my post.

Comment: Beautiful, +1! Perhaps to clarify, I think that it is clear that your first part was a restatement of the problem, and that was exactly why I didn't like it, it was trivially a restatement so that it seemed like no work had been done. But the edit uses a fundamental property of $\mathbb{N}$ to actually prove the restatement, which then proves the desired fact. Even better, it's totally different to how I would have approached it, so I got to learn something too!