# How to prove by contrapositive that for all integers $m$ and $n$, if $m - n$ is odd, then $m$ is odd or $n$ is odd?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So far this is what I've come up with

$p:= m-n$ is odd
$q:= m$ is odd or $n$ is odd

since the contrapositive is defined as $\neg q \implies \neg p$, I have assumed that $m$ is even and $n$ is even (after applying De Morgan's law) and I am now proving that $m-n$ is even. However, this is where I am stuck. Since any even number can be represented as $2$ multiplied by an integer, I have $m = 2a$ and $n = 2b$ and plugging that in gives me $2a - 2b$ which, in the case of $a = b$ equals zero. Is there a way to rewrite this statement so that I can say it holds true in the case that $a$ does not equal $b$?

Answer (score 1):

$2a-2b=2(a-b)$ is an even number since $a-b$ is an integer.

Note that $0$ is an even number as $0=2(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$\mathbb{O}$
and
$\mathbb{E}$
be the sets of
odd and even integers,
respectively.

You want to show that

$$m-n \in \mathbb{O}
\implies
(m \in \mathbb{O})
\lor
(n \in \mathbb{O})
.$$

By De Morgan's laws,
the negation of
the right side is
(where single quote
means negation)

$((m \in \mathbb{O})
\lor
(n \in \mathbb{O}))'\\
=(m \in \mathbb{O})'
\land
(n \in \mathbb{O})'\\
=(m \not\in \mathbb{O})
\land
(n \not\in \mathbb{O})\\
=(m \in \mathbb{E})
\land
(n \in \mathbb{E})\\
$

and the negation of the
left side is

$(m-n \in \mathbb{O})'\\
=(m-n \not\in \mathbb{O})\\
=(m-n \in \mathbb{E}).
$

The contrapositive
is therefore

$((m \in \mathbb{E})
\land
(n \in \mathbb{E}))
\implies
(m-n \in \mathbb{E})
$.

In words:
if $m$ and $n$ are even
then
$m-n$ is even.

This question of mine
might be relevant:
[Prove that no positive integer is both even and odd, and that all positive integers are either even or odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476184/prove-that-no-positive-integer-is-both-even-and-odd-and-that-all-positive-integ)

Answer (score -1):

Well the contrapositive would be that if
 $m$ and $n$ are even, then $m-n$ is even.
Make $m=2a$ and $n=2b$
$$M-n= 2a-2b
=2(a-b)
=2k$$

make $k=a-b$. $2k$ is positive making the contrapositive true therefore making the original statement true.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.